# (php) what's wrong with the conditional operator? there's a function that founds if an associative array have any key

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to redirect the user when the super global variable $_GET["chapter"] it's defined and it does not have a value that I didn't specify:

```
if(isset($_GET["chapter"])){
    $myChapter=$_GET["chapter"];
    if($myChapter!="prelude" OR $myChapter!="chapter-1"){
        header("location:what.php");   
    }
}
```

the problem happens when I set the super global variable $_GET["chapter"] it's defined as prelude or as chapter-1 in the link

```
chapter=prelude
```

the page redirect me to what.php (the error page). If I modify the conditional with a just one condition, the redirect function (header) does not redirect me to what.php. It works

```
if(isset($_GET["chapter"])){
    $myChapter=$_GET["chapter"];
    if($myChapter!="prelude"){
        header("location:what.php");
    }
}
```

if a put a "else if" or another "if" the conditional left to work.

Last question: there is function that found if an associative array have any key?

Comment: `$myChapter!="prelude" OR $myChapter!="chapter-1"`, this expression is always `true`. There is no way you can set a value in `$myChapter` which makes both sub expressions result in `false`.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws on how you might want to rewrite this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you have will always return true. If, e.g., `$myChapter` is `prelude`, it won't be equal to `chapter-1`. It looks like you meant to use the `and` logical operator, not `or`:

```
if ($myChapter != "prelude" and $myChapter != "chapter-1") {
    // Here ----------------^
    header("location:what.php");   
}
```